# Does CSS var() fallback work in unsupported browsers?

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm working with CSS vars these days so one thing has got my mind, I wanna know **if I set a fallback for CSS var() function**, how will this fallback work **in old browsers** which do not support CSS var completely. **Whether will it be applied or considered as an unknown CSS feature**?

To make long story short now I write two lines of CSS for a property like this:

```
:root{
   --box-height: 350px;
}

.box{
   height: 350px; // FALLBACK for older browsers.
   height: var(--box-height);
}
```

my intention is to give fallback for older browsers, but it will be okay if I write that way:

```
:root{
   --box-height: 350px;
}

.box{
   height: var(--box-height, 350px); // Does it work in older browsers really?
}
```

Will it work in older browsers or no? there is no transparent documentation about what I am talking about what is your thought?

Comment: No it won't, `height: var(--box-height, 350px);` is not really a fallback, it just means that 350px will apply if the variable is not defined in modern browsers. But the variable name is not valid css for older browsers.

Comment: But you should really have tested this yourself before asking here.

Comment: @Paulie_D Overwriting properties like this, is this the only way we can do?

Comment: @Paulie_D this is a place for sharing knowledge. I could but I betcha it will be the question of who started using CSS vars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will it work in older browsers or no?

No it won't. If a browser doesn't recognize `var()` then there is no way to consider the fallback value you defined there. The whole value will be invalid.

You should stick to your first syntax if you want to consider old browsers.

Comment: First syntax will not work either. Here's the quote from MDN: `When the browser encounters an invalid var() substitution, then the initial or inherited value of the property is used.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#handling_invalid_custom_properties

Means, the `height` will be set to `initial`, not `350px`.

Comment: @KostiantynKo *When the browser encounters an invalid var() substitution* --> this is the case when the browser *knows* about var() so it's supported and that's what I am talking about. When the browser doesn't support var() it will not even consider that quote and the whole value is ignored and height: 350px will be used.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Just checked IE11 and Safari 11. Since IE does not recognize the CSS variables feature at all, it does benefit from the first approach. While the second approach is absolutely necessary in Safari 11, otherwise you'll get `unset`. So in order to provide a reliable fallback, one must use the combination of both approaches.

Comment: Just to clarify, the second approach might be necessary for older browsers as well because of the way those props are defined in the first place. For example, a custom prop was defined within media query with `prefers-color-scheme: dark`, and the browser (like Safari 11) does not support such a query, thus the prop does not get assigned. Thus the fallback.